# Why does one integral converge and not the other?

Tags: integration

Maybe I am just not thinking this through properly but why does. Or maybe I'm just trusting wolfram alpha too much

(1) Doesn't Converge
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{1.95}} \frac{1}{1-1.95x}dx$$

(2) Does Converge 
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{1.95}} \frac{1.01}{1-1.95x}dx$$
(3) Does Converge 
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{1.95}} \frac{0.99}{1-1.95x}dx$$

I would intuitively think that since (1) doesnt converge and (2) and (3) shouldn't, I may just thinking of this too simply

Comment: I'd like to have some notes on the "Wolfram Alpha computes wrong" part, but this is a mathematics site and it's not relevant. Anyway: If you use a floating point number in input, Mathematica (and Wolfram Alpha) treat it as an inexact number. If the number is inexact the result can be quite inexact (magnified by the fact that the integral diverges). Instead use the fraction instead -- replace `1.01` with `101/100` etc. and Wolfram Alpha [correctly computes that the integral diverges](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(101%2F100)%2F(1-195x%2F100)+for+x+from+0+to+100%2F195).

Comment: Alternatively [there is `Rationalize`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+Rationalize%5B1.01%5D%2F(1-Rationalize%5B1.95%5Dx)+for+x+from+0+to+1%2FRationalize%5B1.95%5D).

Comment: Type **integral (1)/(1-195/100 x)dx  from 0 to 100/195**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all three integrands are scalar multiples one of another, the three integrals should behave analogously. In particular, they all diverge, since
$$\int_0^{\frac1{1.95}}\frac1{1-1.95x}dx=\lim_{a\to{\frac1{1.95}}^-}\frac1{-1.95}\log(1-1.95x)|_0^a=+\infty,$$
and any constant different from one could be taken out of the integral and wouldn't change the result (except for the zero, and for the sign of $\infty$ if it were negative.)

Comment: so is what am i doing here wrong: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+(1.01)%2F(1-1.95x)dx++from+0+to+1%2F1.95

Comment: The thing is that Wolfram is trying to give an aproximate value (a numerical solution) for a problem that doesn't have a solution. And since the reciprocal of $1.95$ is clearly replaced by an aproximation, the answer has become very sensible indeed to minor changes to that one in the numerator. Try changing all $1.95$ ocurrences by $1.25$ and you will see that the answer is consistently the divergence of the integral.

Comment: Computers are never wrong. But we have to be very sure about what they are programmed to do in each situation. Anyhow, when their answers contradict the most basic properties, those we are sure are to hold, it's when we have to stop believing everything they say.

Answer (score 1):

The improper integral is not difficult:
$$
\int_0^{\frac{1}{a}} \frac{y}{1-a x}\, dx
=\lim_{b\to\frac{1}{a}-} \int_0^b\frac{y}{1-a x}\, dx
= \lim_{b\to \frac{1}{a}-}-\frac{y}{a}\ln(1-a x)\bigg|_{x=0}^{b}\tag{1}
$$
where $a=1.95$.
Unless $y=0$, the limit in (1) does not converge.

Answer (score 1):

This definitely seems to be a bug in Wolfram Alpha.  If you look at [computation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%201%2F(1-1.95x)%20from%200%20to%201%2F1.95) lower on the page, it gives the Cauchy principal value of the integral as $16.5433$  Apparently, when the numerator is not $1$, it's reporting the Cauchy principal value as the value of the (divergent) integral.

Comment: ok thats what I thought, I just wanted to make sure I wasnt crazy

Comment: No, you're not.  I reported the bug to Wolfram.

Comment: (not a bug. It's because of the inexact input, see also my comments under the question)